# Can´t get a smooth step by step rotation with CoreAnimation and CALayers

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-animation, calayer

Im trying to rotate a CALayer with various sublayers according to time. There is UDP Multicast receiver in place which will receive new timecodes. I fetch new times via a timer:

```
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02f
 target:self
 selector:@selector(fetchNewTimeAndRotate)
 userInfo:nil
 repeats:YES];
```

The CALayer should be rotated according to time. In my case, one rotation in 1.8 seconds. Actually i dont need any animation, i just need the angle to be set very often, so that it produces the actual animation.

I´ve tried setting the layers rotation in various ways:

1st i tried via CATransform3DMakeRotation:

```
CATransform3D rotation1 = CATransform3DMakeRotation([self DegreesToRadians:newAngle], 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
self.circleLayer.transform=rotation1
```

2nd try was using an instant rotation via an animation:

```
rotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self DegreesToRadians:oldAngle]];
rotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self DegreesToRadians:newAngle]];
rotation.duration = 0.0f;
rotation.repeatCount = 0.0f;
rotation.removedOnCompletion = NO; //also used YES here with no effect
[self.circleLayer addAnimation:rotation forKey:@"transform.rotation.z"];
oldAngle=newAngle;
```

3rd try was just setting an angle to "transform.rotation.z"

```
[self.circleLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[self DegreesToRadians:newAngle]] forKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
```

All of the above approaches do work, but lead to significant stuttering in the rotation. I´ve tried using several different timings in fetching and in animation-length. Nothing seems to get rid of the problem. 
Using an autorotation every 0.02 and an 3.6° angle is the only option that presented smooth results for me. Am i making a fundamental mistake here or didn´t understand the concept of CoreAnimation? I know that it is to be used to make the animation itself. But i need it to react to user input and change immediatly.
Im thankful for any help.

Comment: Is the circle layer a layer that you have created or is it the layer of one of your views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean CADisplayLink, don't you?

DisplayLink objects are commonly used for frame-based animation in OpenGL, but they do not "use OpenGL". It's perfectly valid to create a display link and attach it to your application to trigger drawing.

As the other poster said, NSTimer is not a good choice for fine control of animation frames. If you write a program that just runs a timer and measures it, it will look good. However, timers depend on your app visiting the event loop frequently. They are not preemptive, and if your app is busy when the timer should fire, it will be off, or even miss a firing interval.

If you continue to use a display link, you might want to write your code to check the time elapsed from the last frame and calculate the amount to animated baed on that. That way if you drop a frame the animation still proceeds at the correct velocity (If you drop a frame then twice as much time elapses before the next frame, so you make your objects move twice as much.)

Comment: First of all, thanks. I think CADisplayLink only exists for the iPhone. Im writing an OS.X app, so i need to use CVDisplayLink which is uses OpenGL. Is there a way to use CADisplayLink with an OS.X app? I would love to try that. CVDispayLink is creating a high priority thread which gets informed by OpenGL when the display is ready to redraw. So i have to get into threads, which i really want to avoid(may be a bit much for a spinning disc and i dont have a clue). I know NSTimer can be inaccurate now, but i think it does the job as long as processing time is not used somewhere else.

Comment: Son of a gun, I guess you're right. Almost all of the CA classes are cross-platform, so I assumed that CADisplayLink was too. My mistake. If all you're trying to do is a spinning disk, why don't you use a UIView block animation on the rotation property, with a longer interval like 1/10 of a second, where you rotate from the previous value to the destination value on each interval, and with linear timing? Since each step is an animation, the changes in speed and destination position should be pretty subtle.

Comment: Ok, what im doing is the following: Im getting a time code over the network and have to rotate accordingly. Updates to the disc need to be done as often as possible due to user input. 1/10 of a second is by far not enough, user inputs can come far more rapidly. The only thing i can think of is to let go of CALayers and use OpenGL instead. Coding it myself seems to be the right thing to do here

Comment: I got it working now, i used a CVDisplayLink to trigger the redraw of all CALayers. It was a bit tricky handling the threading part, but i got it working. A big thanks to Duncan and David for their support. CVDisplayLink was the way to go!